# How do I make ListPlot join the points in order?

Tags: plotting, graphics, input

I gave `ListPlot` a set of points to plot and join together. The problem is that It's drawing the line in some way **other than** the order that I input them as.

```
ListPlot[{{1.0, 4.0}, {0.204237675089357, 
   4.6056090506695}, {0.742636892489539, 
   3.76291914168585}, {0.13802394504369, 
   4.55943856001841}, {-0.806180311546581, 4.88879903402343}}, 
 Joined -> True]
```

This is the output:
[image]

I need `ListPlot` to draw the line in the order that I gave the points. How do I do this?

Comment: It looks to me like it's joining them in the order that you put them in.

Comment: @march yea, sorry about that. You are correct. I am just a college student in dire need of sleep :p

Comment: Does anyone know how to draw the path of these points with arrows? I need to clearly show that this is a path. I know it's obvious in this scenario because no lines overlap but in other cases I will have overlapping lines and I need to show the path from point to point.

Comment: `Graphics[Arrow /@ Partition[listOfPoints, 2, 1], Axes -> True]`.

Comment: @march , that is nearly perfect. It seems that doing this shifted my point of origin to (1.0,4.3). How can I fix the x-range to [-8,8] and the y-range to [-8,8]?

Answer (score 3):

```
pts = {
   {1.0, 4.0},
   {0.204237675089357, 4.6056090506695},
   {0.742636892489539, 3.76291914168585},
   {0.13802394504369, 4.55943856001841},
   {-0.806180311546581, 4.88879903402343}};
```

If you label the points you will see that the line is drawn in the order that the points are entered

```
ListPlot[pts,
 Joined -> True,
 Epilog -> (n = 1;
   Text[
      Style[n++, 14, Bold],
      #, {-1, -1}] & /@ pts),
 PlotRange -> {3.7, 5}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Just `SortBy` first element of pair, e.g.:

```
ListPlot[SortBy[{{1.0, 4.0}, {0.204237675089357, 
    4.6056090506695}, {0.742636892489539, 
    3.76291914168585}, {0.13802394504369, 
    4.55943856001841}, {-0.806180311546581, 4.88879903402343}}, 
  First], Joined -> True]
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

`Ordering` will work here too,

```
data = {{1.0, 4.0}, {0.204237675089357,4.6056090506695}, {0.742636892489539, 
3.76291914168585}, {0.13802394504369,4.55943856001841}, {-0.806180311546581, 
4.88879903402343}};
data[[Ordering[data[[All, All]]]]]
```

> {{-0.80618, 4.8888}, {0.138024, 4.55944}, {0.204238, 
>     4.60561}, {0.742637, 3.76292}, {1., 4.}}

```
ListPlot[%, Joined -> True, Frame -> True, PlotStyle -> Red]
```

[image]

Adopting @march suggestion,

```
Graphics[Arrow /@ Partition[data[[Ordering[data[[All, All]]]]], 2, 1],Axes -> True]
```

[image]