# How to build one data from other data ListLinePlot

Tags: plotting, list-manipulation, data

I want to build:

```
ListLinePlot[{en, v1} // Transpose]
```

I want:

[image]

but the third plot is a problem:

```
 data1={1,2,3,4,5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10} (* number of points *)
 data2={3.3, 3.1, 3, 3.5, 3.13, 2.4, 2.12, 2.87, 4.3, 5} (* values of voltage *)
 data3={14, 27, 125, 256, 350, 14, 19, 126, 250, 310} (*values of angle*)

ListLinePlot[{data1, data2}// Transpose] (*It's Okey*)

ListLinePlot[{data1, data3}// Transpose] (*It's Okey*)

ListLinePlot[{data3, data2}// Transpose] (*Picture below*)
```

[image: The X-axis is not equal to the number of points.]

Comment: Did you try to sort the list of points?

Comment: Probably not. How to do it? I try to apply "Thread" and MapIndexed, but there was a mistake in the syntax.

Comment: If the list of points is like {{x1,y1},{x2,y2},{x3,y3}}, then Sort[list, #[[1]]<#2[[1]]&] is quite good. See the complete syntax in the Documentation.

Comment: I have a table, where there is, example, {data1, data2, data3}.
data1 is voltage, data2 is number, example, 5 points, and data3 is angle. I can to build ListLinePlot[{data2, data1} // Transpose, {data2, data3} // Transpose] - No problem. But if I want to build ListLinePlot[{data3,data1}]. I have problem, as a picture.

Comment: do you have to keep the data separated, e.g. to keep their colours different?

Comment: Do those answers fit your needs? [**137444**](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/137444/5478)

Comment: No, I want to replace data 2 with data 3, but with the values saved by the number of points. In the figure above, the X axis contains data 3, but they are not in order, and there are in the range from 0 to 359. But axis X must be in the range [0 ... number points] with different values [0...359]

Comment: @Alex I am sorry I'm not English, but I didn't understand what you actually want to do...

Comment: Is: `ListLinePlot[ SortBy[Transpose@{data3, data2}, First] ]` the answer?

Comment: I've edited your question but next time please add a copyable working example yourself.

Answer (score 1):

So working from the data sample you provided for Kuba in a comment we have this:

```
data1 = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10};
data2 = {3.3, 3.1, 3, 3.5, 3.13, 2.4, 2.12, 2.87, 4.3, 5};
data3 = {14, 27, 125, 256, 350, 14, 19, 126, 250, 310};

Row@
 {
  Transpose@{data1, data2} //
   ListLinePlot[#, ImageSize -> 200] &,
  Transpose@{data1, data3} //
   ListLinePlot[#, ImageSize -> 200] &,
  SortBy[Transpose@{data3, data2}, First] //

   ListLinePlot[#, ImageSize -> 200] &
  }
```

Which gives this as the output:

[image: plots]

Obviously this is dataset too small to know if that's really what you wanted but try it out with the full data.

So I think what you're actually trying to get at is labelling that first plot with the angle values. Here's a way to do it:

```
ListLinePlot[
 Transpose@{data1, data2},
 Ticks -> {
   MapIndexed[{First@#2, #} &, data3],
   Automatic
   }
 ]
```

[image]

Comment: Yes, It is alright. Thank you so much.

Comment: @Alex so then your problem was what Riccardo Cazzin identified. Namely your points needed to be sorted (this was I think everyone's guess from the plots you provided).

Comment: I looked at the answer carefully, and still it's a bit wrong. I want 10 values on the X axis, but only so that they are not in order, but in the same sequence as originally at data3.

Comment: @Alex If they aren't in order in terms of their x-values the line going between them will be a zig-zagging mess, as you saw. Do you want something like `ListPolarPlot`? You said that `data3` is a bunch of angles.

Comment: I want ListLinePlot, but that instead of the number of points along the X axis, the values of the angle without sorting are assigned.
Example Axis X must: {35, 48,167,270,358,24,59,79 and etc.}, that is, instead of the values of the points, the values of the angle without sorting are substituted.

Comment: @Alex I'm afraid I don't know what you mean. If you supply `{35, 48,167,270,358,24,59,79}` paired up with a list of y-values the line connecting the points will zig-zag across the plot. You didn't want that, though, I thought.

Comment: Yes, I want axis X, there values of angle = number of points - in order. See the first picture from Excel. There is axis X (angle), but values are in the order of their receipt.

Comment: @Alex do you mean the stuff in the red box? That's clearly plot labeling, not the actual x values for each point.

Comment: Yes, How build this Axis X, there values angle :=number of points.
data3:=data1.

Comment: @Alex I'm not sure I know what you mean, but your question is really about labeling `ListLinePlot[{data1, data2}// Transpose]` with the data in `data3`. I'll give you an example.

Comment: Yes, I want labeling Axis X -> data3 but in fact there is data1.

Comment: @Alex see if that addition is what you needed. You can play with the tick positioning and orientation of course, but that might be the basic form you wanted.

Comment: Yes, now thanks you so much.