# Rotation of ticks

Tags: plotting, data, labeling, ticks

Where is mistake?

Length[v1]=16384

Length[en]=16384

```
{v1, f1, en, time} = exp[[1, 2 ;;, {6, 7, 8, 9}]] // Transpose;
{v1, n} = exp[[1, 2 ;;, {6, 1}]] // Transpose;

 ListLinePlot[{n, v1} // Transpose, 
 Ticks -> {MapIndexed[{First@#2, Rotate[#, 90 Degree]} &, en], 
   Automatic}, ImageSize -> Medium, PlotRange -> Automatic]
```

[image]

How to reduce the step of "Ticks" values on Axis X?

I test this code:

```
data1 = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10};
data2 = {3.3, 3.1, 3, 3.5, 3.13, 2.4, 2.12, 2.87, 4.3, 5};
data3 = {14, 27, 125, 256, 350, 14, 19, 126, 250, 310};
ListLinePlot[Transpose@{data1, data2}, 
 Ticks -> {MapIndexed[{First@#2, Rotate[#, 90 Degree]} &, data3], 
   Automatic}]
```

It is ok.

```
ListLinePlot[{n, v1} // Transpose, 
 Ticks -> {MapIndexed[{First@#2, Rotate[#, 90 Degree]} &, 
    en[[;; ;; 100]]], Automatic}, ImageSize -> Medium, 
 PlotRange -> Automatic, ImageSize -> Large]
```

[image]

Comment: Don't use `en` but a subset of it for ticks generation? Like `en[[ ;; ;; 10]]`?

Comment: en is subset with length 16384 points. I don't understand. 
`{en}=exp[[1,2;;6}]]`. En is a column of real values from the encoder.

Comment: And you are generating ticks for all points in `en`: `Ticks -> {MapIndexed[{First@#2, Rotate[#, 90 Degree]} &, en]`.

Comment: You mean, that I can decrease length of "en" and generate tick with decreasing length?

Comment: I mean you generate 16k ticks and you have it. Want fewer? Reduce `en` you use in `Ticks`.

Comment: How I can reduce `en`? But save number points of axis Y.

Comment: As @Kuba said: do something like `Ticks -> {MapIndexed[{First@#2, Rotate[#, 90 Degree]} &, en[[ ;; ;; 100]]]`, change the `100` to a value you'll find pleasing. // I'm not sure what's the exact structure of `en` (and don't have MMA now around to play with some made-up data), so maybe you'll have to use `en[[ ;; 10]]` or so. Generally, you want to display every 100th number on the x-axis.

Comment: Alex If you look in [your original posting](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/140077/how-to-build-one-data-from-other-data-listlineplot) they don't label every single point. Consider [the image you provided](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xpMVRm.jpg) where these values are the ones in the box. Changing the tick specification *will not* affect the appearance of your plot at all. If you do what what @Kuba suggested you'll get what you wanted.

Comment: @MB1965 If I change value, example, `en[[ ;; ;; 100]]`, I get, that 100 points. But they do not correspond to the points - the counts along the axis. You see last picture in this post.

Comment: @Alex, well, yes, you'll need to adjust the count position it aligns with. Try `{MapIndexed[{100*(First@#2-1)+1, Rotate[#, 90 Degree]} &,  en[[;; ;; 100]]], Automatic}`. Please read the documentation on `Ticks`. It seems to me as if you haven't.